# Add library to RubyMine

Tags: ruby, spell-checking, rubymine

Is there a way to tell RubyMine to take into account some library so that every time you type some method it defines, RubyMine won't underline it? It's really annoying right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed some Ruby gem and want RubyMine to consider it, define it in the `Gemfile` as described in the [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/ruby-gems-support.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to start a new project in Ruby Mine, add a gem to it, and test it out. This example adds the popular `ActiveSupport` and `i18n` libraries

#### Create a new project and use some gems

- Start Ruby Mine
- Choose "File | New Project | Empty Project"
- Choose "Tools | Bundler | init" to create a new "Gemfile", which will be opened up immediately after in the IDE.
- Add the following 2 lines to the gem file:

    `gem "activesupport"
    gem "i18n"`
- Choose "Tools | Bundler | Install". Your gems will be installed, and now your project can use these gems.

#### Use the gems in a simple example

- Choose "File | New... | Ruby Class" to add an empty class file to your project, call it "Test"
- The following is some example code that uses activesupport.

#### test.rb

```
  require "active_support/all"

  def last_games(games, index)
    games.from(index)
  end
  games = ["Super Mario Bros.", "Contra", "Metroid", "Mega Man 2"]
  puts last_games(games, 2)
```

- Save your file, and now right click in the file and choose "Run test"
- Your code should run and output the following to the RubyMine console!

> Metroid
>     Mega Man 2